# Add PDF file to GitHub repo after latex-action

Tags: latex, github-actions

I'm using https://github.com/xu-cheng/latex-action in my workflow to compile a `.tex` file.

The action end successfully but the `.pdf` file is located in the CI environment and I'm willing to configure the workflow to somehow add the file to my repository.

How can I publish the `.pdf` file in the repository in the same commit?

Workflow implementation:

```
name: Build LaTeX document
on: [push]
jobs:
  build_latex:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Set up Git repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        
      - name: Compile LaTeX document
        uses: xu-cheng/latex-action@v2
        with:
          root_file: file1.tex
```

Comment: Ok. Did you try using the `working directory` input using the `$GITHUB_WORKSPACE` to see if the pdf was at the repository root? Otherwise, there is a section on the action README explaining [how to upload the PDF](https://github.com/xu-cheng/latex-action#where-is-the-pdf-file-how-to-upload-it). And if you want to use a git step to commit the file, you could use ```- name: Commit and Push new file
        run: |
          git config user.name <username>
          git config user.email <email>
          git add .
          git commit -m "add PDF file"
          git push```

Comment: Hi! First, thanks for helping. The first method you suggested does not work for some reason. The second does, but that would double each commit I perform, is there any way for adding the pdf file to the same commit?

Comment: I guess that to do it in the same commit, this operation would have to be performed through the action implementation [here](https://github.com/xu-cheng/latex-action/blob/master/entrypoint.sh). It doesn't seem to be available at the moment. So if that's a problem in your context, you could eventually add this suggestion as an ISSUE in the action repository. You could also create your own action based on this one with a fork, updating the shell file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to create a release and then uploading the generated file as release.

```
  - name: Release
    id: release
    uses: actions/create-release@v1
    env:
      GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
    with:
      tag_name: ${{ github.ref }}
      release_name: Release ${{ github.ref }} ${{ github.event.head_commit.message }}
      draft: false
      prerelease: false
  - name: Upload 
    id: upload
    uses: actions/upload-release-asset@v1
    env:
      GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
    with:
      upload_url: ${{ steps.create_release.outputs.upload_url }}
      asset_path: ./file1.pdf
      asset_name: file1.pdf
      asset_content_type: pdf
```

Comment: if I have multiple tex files, is there a way to upload only the pdf's generated from the files that was changed in the current commit?